# Renaming Object using Google Cloud Function using Python 3

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am running the below code from my cloud function:

```
from google.cloud import storage


def rename_blob(bucket_name, blob_name, new_name):
    """Renames a blob."""
    bucket_name = "gk-12345"
    blob_name = "gk.txt"
    new_name = "gk-2343.txt"

    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(blob_name)

    print(blob)
    print(new_name)

    new_blob = bucket.rename_blob(blob, new_name)

    print("Blob {} has been renamed to {}".format(blob.name, new_blob.name))
```

I am getting below error:

> Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for
>   termination reason. Details: rename_blob() missing 2 required
>   positional arguments: 'blob_name' and 'new_name'

The code snippet is from https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/renaming-copying-moving-objects#code-samples_2

Could someone please help.

Thank you!

**EDIT**

I made change to the code:

```
 from google.cloud import storage
import datetime


def rename_blob(bucket_name, blob_name=None, destination_bucket_name=None,destination_blob_name=None):
    """Copies a blob from one bucket to another with a new name."""
    #time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H%M%S")
    #bucket_name = "gk-12345"
    #blob_name = "gk.txt"
    #destination_bucket_name = "gk-12345"
    #destination_blob_name = blob_name+time


    storage_client = storage.Client()

    source_bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    source_blob = source_bucket.blob(blob_name)
    destination_bucket = storage_client.bucket(destination_bucket_name)

    blob_copy = source_bucket.copy_blob(
        source_blob, destination_bucket, destination_blob_name
    )

    print(
        "Blob {} in bucket {} copied to blob {} in bucket {}.".format(
            source_blob.name,
            source_bucket.name,
            blob_copy.name,
            destination_bucket.name,
        )
    )

time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H%M%S")
bucket_name = "gk-12345"
bName = "gk.txt"
dbName = "gk-12345"
dbNameTime = bName+time
rename_blob(bucket_name, blob_name=bName, destination_bucket_name=dbName,destination_blob_name=dbNameTime)
```

I get below error now:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py", line 346, in run_http_function result = _function_handler.invoke_user_function(flask.request) File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py", line 217, in invoke_user_function return call_user_function(request_or_event) File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py", line 210, in call_user_function return self._user_function(request_or_event) File "/user_code/main.py", line 16, in rename_blob source_bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name) File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/client.py", line 270, in bucket return Bucket(client=self, name=bucket_name, user_project=user_project) File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/bucket.py", line 512, in __init__ name = _validate_name(name) File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/_helpers.py", line 51, in _validate_name if not all([name[0].isalnum(), name[-1].isalnum()]): File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 377, in <lambda> __getitem__ = lambda x, i: x._get_current_object()[i] TypeError: 'Request' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note your error:

```
Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for termination reason. Details: rename_blob() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'blob_name' and 'new_name'
```

It's telling you that it's missing 'blob_name' and 'new_name'. Is `rename_blob` the entry point you've specified for the Cloud Function? Or is there more code in the function that you haven't put in here?

Whatever is triggering the function isn't passing in the two variables for `blob_name` and `new_name`, it's only passing in the `bucket_name` (whether that's some other code you haven't pasted from inside the function, or whatever is triggering the function).

You can technically "fix" that error by making it `rename_blob(bucket_name)` since you're hardcoding everything anyway.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I added the full code with new error.

Answer (score 0):

> Problem is in your function's parameters.
>   
> Maybe you're calling your function without passing all 3 parameters.

```
def rename_blob(bucket_name, blob_name, new_name):
```

Replace above line with below code:

```
def my_rename_blob():
```

Comment: Thank you for responding, I get below error now: `code` Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for termination reason. Details:
rename_blob() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Comment: @techmate How you're calling the function? Can you share the full code?

Comment: I have added the full code and new error to the post

Answer (score 0):

The final code:

```
from google.cloud import storage
import datetime


def rename_blob(bucket_name):
    """Copies a blob from one bucket to another with a new name."""
    time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H%M%S")
    bucket_name = "gk-12345"
    blob_name = "gk.txt"
    destination_bucket_name = "gk-12345"
    destination_blob_name = blob_name+time


    storage_client = storage.Client()

    source_bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    source_blob = source_bucket.blob(blob_name)
    destination_bucket = storage_client.bucket(destination_bucket_name)

    blob_copy = source_bucket.copy_blob(
        source_blob, destination_bucket, destination_blob_name
    )

    print(
        "Blob {} in bucket {} copied to blob {} in bucket {}.".format(
            source_blob.name,
            source_bucket.name,
            blob_copy.name,
            destination_bucket.name,
        )
    )
```